How to set up a local DNS server with SSL security using Let’s Encrypt?
I want to set up a secure local DNS server with SSL/TLS support on Ubuntu Server 22.04.4, preferably using Let’s Encrypt for certificates. In the past, I used Webmin and BIND9, but it didn’t work as expected. Now, I’m looking to create a secure and fast local DNS server from scratch.
What’s the best approach to setting up a local DNS server with SSL/TLS on Ubuntu Server 22.04.4?
How can I use Let’s Encrypt certificates for DNS server security?
Is there a better alternative to BIND9 for performance and security?
Any guidance, step-by-step instructions, or resources would be greatly appreciated.

This EXACT SAME question was asked yesterday. Since it has been deleted I can not recall the user name.

I accidentally deleted that. If you know the answer, please provide it.
